# Permisos para llamadas XMLHttpRequest usando el plugin Uploadifive

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, fileupload

Que tal amigos tengo un problema al usar el plugin Uploadifive, para subir múltiples imágenes a mi servidor, este plugin usa el servicio de XMLHttpRequest. Yo tengo un archivo .htaccess que bloque el acceso a los directorios y archivos, pero agregué el permiso para AJAX, y funciona correcto pero no para el plugin ya que me genera un error 403 de acceso denegado. Revisando el js de uploadifive.js agregué un header pero aún así nada, alguien solucionó este problema?, dejo aquí mi código, gracias de antemano.

---

Código del archivo uploadifive.js donde agregué un header de: X-Requested-With

```
xhr.open(settings.method, settings.uploadScript, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
```

Código del archivo donde uso el plugin para enviar las fotos:

```
$('#file_upload').uploadifive({
  'auto'             : false,
  //'checkScript'      : 'programacion_file_check.php',
  'formData'         : {
                         'timestamp' : '0',
                         'token'     : '0',
                         'action'    : 'insertar',
                         'gar_id' : '0'
                       },
  'queueID'          : 'queue',
  'uploadScript'     : 'http://localhost/ipdnbeta/vista/garantiafile/garantiafile_controller.php',
  'queueSizeLimit'   : 10,
  'uploadLimit'      : 10,
  'multi'            : true,
  'buttonText'       : 'Seleccionar Archivo',
  'height'           : 20,
  'width'            : 180,
  'fileSizeLimit'    : '5MB',
  'fileType'         : ["image\/gif","image\/jpeg","image\/png","image\/jpg"],
  'onUploadComplete' : function(file, data) {
    console.log(data);     
  }
```

finalmente mi código en el .htaccess, donde tengo permitido a AJAX, pero no funciona para el plugin uploadifive:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest ajax                    
<Files ~ "\.(php)$">
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from env=ajax                                                  
</Files>
```

Comment: `<Files ~ "\.(php)$">` y `</Files>` van en líneas separadas

Comment: si amigo, en mi código está separado, sino que aquí sale así en una sola línea

Comment: editado amigo, tienes alguna idea de cómo solucionar este problema?

Comment: eso es lo que me extraña, que no funciona como si el plugin de uploadifive usara otros servicios, has usado también ese plugin?

Comment: no jamás, pero podés revisar en tu server qué headers está enviando para verificarlo

Comment: el plugin solo envía dos headers, ojalá puedas hacer una prueba y me puedas ayudar amigo

Comment: No lo pude reproducir al error, aunque me imagino que viene por el lado de CORS, probablemente en el pre-flight cuando la solicitud AJAX pida OPTIONS... Pero sin obtener el error, me es imposible responder. ¿Te aparece algo en la consola (asegurate de no estar filtrando las solicitudes de XMLHttpRequest)? ¿Y qué pasa si le sacás el Deny, se obtiene la página por AJAX o te da algún error de CORS?

Comment: si le quito el Deny, la solicitud se envía con normalidad, el archivo garantiafile_controller.php me devuelve un echo correctamente, pero si le arego el Deny al .htaccess, no ingresa al archivo PHP, directamente en consola el "data", me genera un código html de error 403

Answer (score 0):

La solución si a alguien le pasa lo mismo, es agregar en su .htaccess una variable al igual que la variable AJAX. Quedaría de esta manera:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest ajax            
SetEnvIfNoCase Content-Type ".*" tipo                                  
<Files ~ "\.(php)$">
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from env=ajax
  Allow from env=tipo                                                
</Files>
```